# WPF - Strange behavior when disabling button in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button

I have a `ListView` with some rows. You can select an item in the list and then you get a detailed view (master details view).

In the details view I have a button. When you click on a button, it disables it and does some expensive operation.

The issue is that for some reason, all buttons get disabled for all rows?
Am I missing something here?

```
private void BtnGetStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {            
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn.DataContext is ListCollectionView view) {
        if (view.CurrentItem is MyViewModel viewModel) {
            // Strange - Disables all buttons not currently clicked
            btn.IsEnabled = false;

            BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = false };
            _worker.DoWork += (se, ev) => {
                // Simulate Expensive operation
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);                        
            };
            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (se, ev) => {
                // Strange - enables all buttons not just clicked
                btn.IsEnabled = true;
            };
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();                    
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simple example that demonstrates the issue.
If you click on a button and go to other rows buttons are collapsed.

Only cliked one should be

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="detailsUserTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel>
                <Button Name="BtnGetStatus" Click="BtnGetStatus_Click"
                        Content="Click to start Expensive Operation">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <CollectionViewSource 
          Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.Users}}"   
          x:Key="dataViewSource" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Name="lv_data" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataViewSource}}"
              SelectionMode="Single">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=UserID}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Username" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Username}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Is Enabled" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="Auto"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource detailsUserTemplate}"
                    Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataViewSource}}">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<User> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<User>
                {
                    new User {UserID = 1, Username = "user 1", IsEnabled = true},
                    new User {UserID = 2, Username = "User 2", IsEnabled =true},
                    new User {UserID = 3, Username = "Username 3", IsEnabled = true},
                    new User {UserID = 4, Username = "Username 4", IsEnabled = false}
                };
            }
        }

        private void BtnGetStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;

            btn.IsEnabled = false;
            btn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker()
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = false
            };

            worker.DoWork += (se, ev) =>
            {
                // Simulate expensive
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            };

            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (se, ev) =>
            {
                btn.IsEnabled = true;
                btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            };

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();                    
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your second event handler has not been taken into account... I will seek into it

Comment: You should look into MVVM.  Make that a command exposed from a viewmodel which you use for each row. You can then use canexecute to drive disabling the command and know which button was clicked. Also look into async await and run a task in a background thread, await the result then switch an enabled flag back.

Comment: @Andy I didnt mentioned Iam using .net 4.0. MVVM wouldnt make any difference here. Issue is that once btn.IsEnabled is called every button becomes disabled. Once the expensive operation is done and btn.IsEnabled = true all buttons are again enabled. Why is that ? Thx

Comment: You've not provided a minimal reproduction of your issue so all anyone can do is guess. Click is a routed event that bubbles. I guess you're handling it somewhere the event bubbles through for all of them. You can probably handle it at listview level and use e.originalsource for the button. Mvvm would make a difference because the icommand fired would be in the datacontext of the one specific row where the user clicked the button.

Comment: @Andy I added an working example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you only have one button and this is not related to the selecteditem of your listview.

You disable it and that one button is disabled.

You would need to associate that state with a specific User and bind state of a templated button to that.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:User}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Name="BtnGetStatus"
                            Click="BtnGetStatus_Click"
                            Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                        Content="Click to start Expensive Operation">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <CollectionViewSource 
          Source="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.Users}}"   
          x:Key="dataViewSource" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Name="lv_data" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataViewSource}}"
              SelectionMode="Single">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=UserID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Username" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Username}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Is Enabled" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=lv_data, Path=SelectedItem}">
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The button binds it's state.

Each User now has a state to present to it's templated-button and is related to the selected item.

I've implemented inotifypropertychanged so as the property changes the view will pick up the new value.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<User> Users
        {
            get
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<User>
                {
                    new User {UserID = 1, Username = "user 1", IsEnabled = true},
                    new User {UserID = 2, Username = "User 2", IsEnabled =true},
                    new User {UserID = 3, Username = "Username 3", IsEnabled = true},
                    new User {UserID = 4, Username = "Username 4", IsEnabled = false}
                };
            }
        }

        private async void BtnGetStatus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            User selectedUser = btn.DataContext as User;

            if (selectedUser==null)
            {
                return;
            }
            selectedUser.IsEnabled = false;
            selectedUser.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            await Task.Run(() => doStuffAsync(selectedUser));
            selectedUser.IsEnabled = true;
            selectedUser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        private async Task<bool> doStuffAsync(User user)
        {
            // Do something expensive
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            return true;
        }

    }

    public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        private bool isEnabled;

        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get { return isEnabled; }
            set { isEnabled = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        private Visibility visibility;

        public Visibility Visibility
        {
            get { return visibility; }
            set { visibility = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thx this is the solution. I really didnt Know that this is a default behavior. New to WPF :-) Could you recommend some links where I can find more info about this behavior ?